# Pandas: Determine if a string in one column is a substring of a string in another column

Tags: python, pandas, substring

Consider these series:

```py
>>> a = pd.Series('abc a abc c'.split())
>>> b = pd.Series('a abc abc a'.split())
>>> pd.concat((a, b), axis=1)
     0    1
0  abc    a
1    a  abc
2  abc  abc
3    c    a

>>> unknown_operation(a, b)
0 False
1 True
2 True
3 False
```

The desired logic is to determine if the string in the left column is a substring of the string in the right column. `pd.Series.str.contains` does not accept another Series, and `pd.Series.isin` checks if the value exists in the other series (not in the same row specifically). I'm interested to know if there's a vectorized solution (not using `.apply` or a loop), but it may be that there isn't one.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you are out of luck here and must revert to apply or list comprehensions. Would be loved to be proven wrong!

Comment: @hirolau numpy defchararray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try with `numpy` `defchararray` which is vectorized

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find
find(df['1'].values.astype(str),df['0'].values.astype(str))!=-1
Out[740]: array([False,  True,  True, False])
```

Comment: @SteeleFarnsworth the vectorized one , but not sure about the speed , sometime the appply and for loop isn't that bad ~

Comment: Apparently this is deprecated in favor of [`numpy.char.find()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.find.html).

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
df[1].str.split('', expand=True).eq(df[0], axis=0).any(axis=1) | df[1].eq(df[0])
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Note that this answers the question, but it's worth noting that it's probably faster to just write a for loop with `.tolist()`.

Comment: Yes. `.str` the string accessor is very loopy internally and quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

I tested various functions with a randomly generated Dataframe of 1,000,000 5 letter entries.

Running on my machine, the averages of 3 tests showed:

zip > v_find > to_list > any > apply

0.21s > 0.79s > 1s > 3.55s > 8.6s

Hence, i would recommend using zip:

```
[x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

or vectorized find (as proposed by BENY)

```
np.char.find(df['B'].values.astype(str), df['A'].values.astype(str)) != -1
```

My test-setup:

```
    def generate_string(length):
return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=length))

A = [generate_string(5) for x in range(n)]
B = [generate_string(5) for y in range(n)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": A, "B": B})

to_list = pd.Series([a in b for a, b in df[['A', 'B']].values.tolist()])

apply = df.apply(lambda s: s["A"] in s["B"], axis=1)

v_find = np.char.find(df['B'].values.astype(str), df['A'].values.astype(str)) != -1

any = df["B"].str.split('', expand=True).eq(df["A"], axis=0).any(axis=1) | df["B"].eq(df["A"])

zip = [x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

Comment: Zip is reliable and configurable (can add try except) if your data is not super clean.